# spyOn function not working as intended

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My controller does something like the below:

```
.controller('demo',function($scope,$state, $modal,$q, Resource1, Resource2) {

  function1(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     Resource1.get(function(result){
         $scope.player = result;
         deferred.resolve(promise);
     });
     return deferred.promise;
  }  

  function2() { /* similar to function1. It also returns a promise */ }

   $q.all(function1(),function2(),function(result){

   });

});
```

I have pushed myself sofar...beyond this i am kindof lost. First i am wondering if I am initializing things correctly and secondly  how to write a unit test that will test that function1() was called and that Resource1 was called after that. This is what I have so far:

```
describe('demo',function(){


  beforeEach(function(){
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      q = $injector.get('$q');
      state = $injector.get('$state');
   });

  createController = function(){
      return $controller('demo',{
        $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
        $state: state,
        $modal: sinon.stub({}),
        $q: q,
        Resource1: mockResource1, /*how and where to initialize mock Resources */
        Resource2: mockResource2, 

      });

    } //end beforeEach

   it('should check that func1 was called',function(){
          spyOn(this,'function1');
          var controller = createController();
          expect(this.function1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

   it('should check that Resource1.get as called',function(){
          //  how to formulate the test here 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `function1` is a function which exists inside controller's scope. You can't "touch" it so you can't "spy on" it.